# Using width for caption introduces offset of said caption

Tags: captions

I wanted to use

```
\usepackage[width=0.75\textwidth]{caption}
```

To adjust the width of my caption to the width of the table. However, it introduces a significant offset of the caption.

Without the setting above:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
%% Sets page size and margins
\usepackage[a4paper,top=3cm,bottom=2cm,left=3cm,right=3cm,marginparwidth=1.75cm]{geometry}
%% set width of captions to width of table
%\usepackage[width=0.75\textwidth]{caption}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
  \caption{\label{tab:tab}Bliblablubb, why does this have an offset I wonder? Bliblablubb, why does thi
  \begin{tabular}{l|cccr}
    \textbf{asdasd} & \textbf{cvbcvbce} & asdasdasdasds & sdsdsdsdsdsdsds& sdsdsdsdsdssd\\
    \hline
         asdf           &            &    &      &   \\
                        &            &    &      &   \\
                        &            &    &      &   \\
                        &            &    &      &   \\   
         \hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Table and caption look like this:

[image: No offset of caption but it is too wide]

If I comment in the `\usepackage[width=0.75\textwidth]{caption}` line, it looks like this:

[image]

While the caption has the right width, it is significantly offset. I do not understand the reason for this.

Comment: Use threeparttable instead.

Comment: The caption is centered (use showframe option of geometry to see it).  You could put the caption into a minipage using the desired width.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, usually tables are centered in the available text width. In your case the table was not centered.

Please see the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[%
  a4paper,
  top=3cm,bottom=2cm,left=3cm,right=3cm,
  marginparwidth=1.75cm,
  showframe % <=========================================================
]{geometry}

\usepackage[%
  width=0.75\textwidth, % <=============================================
% margin={0cm,0cm}
]{caption}


\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
  \caption{Bliblablubb, why does this have an offset I wonder? Bliblablubb, why does this happen?} % <=====
  \label{tab:tab} % <===================================================
  \centering % <========================================================
  \begin{tabular}{l|cccr}
    \textbf{asdasd} & \textbf{cvbcvbce} & asdasdasdasds & sdsdsdsdsdsdsds& sdsdsdsdsdssd\\
    \hline
    asdf            &                   &               &                &   \\
                    &                   &               &                &   \\
                    &                   &               &                &   \\
                    &                   &               &                &   \\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

and its result:

[image: resulting pdf]

As you can see I centered the table with command `\centering` and now caption and table have the same with and are both centered.

If you insist in having your table **not** centered, you have to use option `margin={0cm,0.25\textwidth}` (setting left margin to 0, right margin to `0.25\textwidth`) instead `width=0.75\textwidth`, which is printed centered!

I personally prefer centered tables and figures!

Comment: If you fill in some text in the column and increase the table with, the table and the caption is not flush anymore. Also if you shorten the caption, caption and table do not line up. In principle, you have to measure the width of the table, and calculate the width of the caption based on the width of the table. Unless, your table has defined width.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an MWE using [threeparttable](https://ctan.org/pkg/threeparttable). All lined up nicely. I added [array](https://ctan.org/pkg/array) and used the `\extrarowheight` command to add some space between rules and cell content, and removed the side bearings with `@{}`. I have to add that you also may use `\usepackage[margin={0mm, 35mm}]{caption}`. However, with threeparttable, you do not need to guess:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
%% Sets page size and margins
\usepackage[a4paper,top=3cm,bottom=2cm,left=3cm,right=3cm,marginparwidth=1.75cm]{geometry}
%% threeparttableset set width of captions to width of table
\usepackage{caption, threeparttable, array}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{Bliblablubb, why does this have an offset I wonder? Bliblablubb, why does this\label{tab:tab}}
\begin{tabular}{@{}l|cccr@{}}
\textbf{asdasd} & \textbf{cvbcvbce} & asdasdasdasds & sdsdsdsdsdsdsds& sdsdsdsdsdssd\\
 \hline
asdf         &       &    &      &   \\
                &       &    &      &   \\
                &       &    &      &   \\
                &       &    &      &   \\   
         \hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{threeparttable}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```